# CSS/jQuery full screen slide with next/previous buttons

Tags: jquery, css, slide, horizontal-scrolling

I have a full screen site I'm working on with 5 divs at 1960 within a container of 9800 along with a top bar that has a "previous" and "next" button.

The goal is to slide over 1960 to the next slide with the buttons staying constant. Now I have everything setup and working to the point where everything is laid out, the basic animation is working but was I curious about a few things;

1. With the buttons I'm trying to figure out how to make it so when you're on the first slide have it say "back home" and "next" and then say you click on "next" and the new slide comes in I would need to change "back home" to "previous". Then on the last slide visa versa.
2. Also, how would I put in a "start" and "end" cause currently when clicking next even after slide 5 it will keep going.

Current jquery:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".next_p").click(function () {
        $("#projects").animate({
            marginLeft: "-=1960px"
        });
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possible solution (numerous solutions exist):

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/KML9k/1/)**

Html

```
<a href="#" class="prev_p">Previous</a>

<a href="#" class="start">Start</a>

<a href="#" class="next_p">Next</a>
    <div id="projects">
        <div class="slide gray"></div>
        <div class="slide white"></div>
        <div class="slide black"></div>
        <div class="slide gray"></div>
        <div class="slide white"></div>
        <div class="slide black"></div>
    </div>
```

CSS

```
#projects {
    position:relative;
    float:left;
    width:9800px;
    height:300px;
    overflow:hidden;
}
.slide {
    position:relative;
    float:left;
    border:1px solid black;
    width:1960px;
    height:300px;
}
.gray {
    background-color:gray;
}
.white {
    background-color:white;
}
.black {
    background-color:black;
}
```

jQuery

```
$(function () {
     $(".prev_p").hide();
     $(".start").hide();
     var slidewidth = 1960; //in Pixels
     var animationSpeed = 300; //in Milliseconds

     //start page
     $(".start").click(function () {
         $("#projects").animate({
             marginLeft: "0px"
         }, animationSpeed, function () {
             $(".start").hide();
             $(".prev_p").hide();
             $(".next_p").show();
         });
     });
     //next page
     $(".next_p").click(function () {
         $("#projects").animate({
             marginLeft: "-=" + slidewidth + "px"
         }, animationSpeed, function () {
             //check location after animation and hide controls
             //that no longer serve a purpose and add those that do
             var marginLeft = $("#projects").css("margin-left");
             var numberOfSlides = 5;
             if (marginLeft == "-" + (slidewidth * (numberOfSlides - 2)) + "px") {
                 $(".next_p").hide();
             }
             if (marginLeft != "0px") $(".start").show();
             else $(".start").hide();
             $(".prev_p").show();
         });

     });
     //previous page
     $(".prev_p").click(function () {
         $("#projects").animate({
             marginLeft: "+=" + slidewidth + "px"
         }, animationSpeed, function () {
             //check location after animation and hide controls
             //that no longer serve a purpose and add those that do
             var marginLeft = $("#projects").css("margin-left");
             if (marginLeft == "0px") {
                 $(".prev_p").hide();
                 $(".start").hide();
             } else {
                 $(".start").show();
             }
             $(".next_p").show();
         });

     });
 });
```

Comment: You are truly a gentleman and a scholar, sir. This was life saving and perfect.. I wanted something just simple and to the point without a plugin and this did it. This is what I wound up with http://jsfiddle.net/GPXsn/

Comment: Hey Michael.. So I had to go back and redo my structure making everything responsive and getting rid of the fixed widths. Now I've been battling with trying to get this jQuery fixed to fit the new structure.. any tips? Currently its making the images it seems full width on click. I set a container width and it seems to work on larger resolutions but still gets larger on smaller.. which doesn't make sense. Thanks again!

Comment: @Sneezy Updated jsFiddle to use width of slide in stylesheet. So you should be able to set it to something different for mobile devices and the code will work the same.  http://jsfiddle.net/KML9k/2/  This will not work if you resize the browser because it's set on page load. You could use a onResize function to change the size if you'd like. But this should suit your purposes.

Comment: I really appreciate the help man especially the quick response. I tried using the onResize but I wasn't entirely sure where to place it. But ya I'll need to keep the images adaptive to the browser size. I made a quick jsFiddle to show my HTML and CSS to maybe shed a little more light on my situation. http://jsfiddle.net/e9aWL/3/

Again, thanks a ton man.